# XPath returning unexpected elements

Tags: html, xpath

So I have a document with multiple `div`s.

using the path '`//div[1]`' seems? to be returning multiple elements.

thoughts?

Comment: Please accept the answer given below, and also accept answers to many of your previous questions that you forgot to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` is a shorthand in XPath for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` *including* the leading and trailing slashes.  So `//div[1]` fully expanded means

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::div[1]
```

i.e. every `div` element anywhere in the document that is the first `div` child of its respective parent.

If you want just the first `div` in the whole document then you need parentheses:

```
(//div)[1]
```

or use the `descendant::` axis explicitly

```
/descendant::div[1]
```